# What does "downright salivate" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

> Heck, the CRO case studies CopyHackers, Unbounce, and ContentVerve have published over the last few years are enough to make a startup owner downright salivate:

What does "downright salivate" mean here?

Answer (score 1):

"Salivating" is used metaphorically here: when you "drool over" something, it means you want it a lot. "Downright" is an emphatic that carries the connotations of directness, certainty, and strength. So if startup owners are downright salivating over something, it must be quite intensely desirable to them.